# Division by couples

Tags: postgresql-9.5

How can it be possible to obtain a division for all the couples in my table?

I have:

```
ref alt
 A   T
 A   T
 C   G
 A   A
```

The frequency is obtained by:

number_couple / total_number

Where number_couple is the number of times a single couple is in the db. For AT is 2 so 2/4. The others are 1/4 and 1/4.

How can I obtain the frequency for each couple?

Comment: For each pair, can they appear either way round?

Comment: Yep, there can be AT or TA but TA is a different couple from AT, they don't share the same meaning for my purpose, is AT is twice and TA once AT=2/3 and TA=1/3. The same from C,G,T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select ref, alt, 
       count(*)::numeric / (select count(*) from the_table)
from the_table
group by ref, alt
```

Comment: Nice. Also: `count(*)::numeric / sum(count(*)) over ()`